# how to change gently div's size by using animation or something, when it's clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dropdown, effect

I'm just trying to change gently div's size. 
When I click that `div`, I can unfold and fold those `h5` elements
but how can I adapt animation about this action?
I already tried to apply keyframe animation or css transition, but I failed

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  $('#sampleNumberList').append('<h5>#' + i + '</h5>');
}
$('#topSampleNum').on('click', function() {
  if ($('#sampleNumberList').hasClass('active') === true) {
    $('#sampleNumberList').removeClass('active');
  } else {
    $('#sampleNumberList').addClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
.topFloatBar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#sampleNumberList {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="topFloatBar" id="topSampleNum">
  <h2 id="mainNumber"> #1 </h2>
  <div id="sampleNumberList"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please write key frame and classes you used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```js
var sampleList = document.querySelector('#sampleNumberList');
var listTrigger = document.querySelector('#mainNumber');

for(var i=1; i<=10; i++){
  let el = document.createElement('h5');
  el.innerText = i;
  sampleList.append(el);
}

listTrigger.addEventListener('click', ()=> {sampleList.classList.toggle('active');});
```

```css
.topFloatBar{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index:5;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor:pointer;
  }

    #sampleNumberList {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    height: auto;
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transform-origin: top;
  }

.active{transform: scale(1) !important;}
```

```html
<div class="topFloatBar" id="topSampleNum" >
    <h2 id="mainNumber">#1</h2>
    <div id="sampleNumberList"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: jQuery version?

Comment: Not sure why you'd opt for JQuery over vanilla JS, but sure: `for(var i=1; i<=10; i++){let el = $('<h5></h5>');$(el).text(i);$('#sampleNumberList').append(el);}
$('#mainNumber').on('click', function(){$('#sampleNumberList').toggleClass('active');});`

Comment: Because it was tagged jQuery and OPs code is in jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery slideToggle() to smoothly toggle those h5.

See Demo: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v41p82fo/)

```js
$('#clickableDiv').click(function() {
  $('h5').slideToggle();
});
```

```css
#sampleNumberList>h5 {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style='background:red'>
  <h2 id='mainNumber'> #1 </h2>
  <div id='clickableDiv' style='background:yellow'> Click Me </div>
  <div id='sampleNumberList' style='background:blue'>
    <h5> #1 </h5>
    <h5> #2 </h5>
    <h5> #3 </h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1. Please TEST your code and set all settings in JSFiddle correctly: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/4jvcsLjc/ 2. Instead of JSFiddle, use the `<>` snippet editor